# How to combine JS graph in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, graph

I want to create a graph showing the rate EUR/USD at any given moment (when the rate change) from the time the page loads.

The goal to show the customer how the rate of dollar / euro changed into GRAPH.JS at anytime since the entry to the page.

```
 <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
    ?>

<div id="responseText"></div>

<script>
// run the function, it will re-run itself
fetchRate();

function fetchRate() {
    // create the new AJAX Object
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // this handles the request
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            // if the request came back successfully
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                // write the response to a div
                div = document.getElementById("responseText")
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<br />'+ xmlhttp.responseText;
            }else{
            // if the request had an error
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<br />Error fetching rates error code : '+xmlhttp.status;
            }
            // rerun this function to fetch updates
            setTimeout(fetchRate,10000);
        }
    };
    // open the AJAX Object
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?= basename(__FILE__) ?>?fetchOnly", true);
    // send the AJAX request
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['fetchOnly'])){
    $from   = 'eur';
    $to     = 'usd';
    $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s='. $from . $to .'=X'; 
    $response = array();
    $handle = fopen($url, 'r'); 
    if ($handle) { 

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) 
        { 
            $response['rate'] = $data[1]; 
            $response['time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
        fclose($handle);

    }  
?>    



<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script src="Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <br>


echo<<<print

 <script>
        var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100 * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1));
        };
        var randomColorFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        };
        var randomColor = function(opacity) {
            return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
        };

        var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],

                datasets: [{

                    data: [
                     print;

                    <?php
                   echo '{x: ';
    echo $response['rate'];
        echo ',y:';
    echo $response['time'];
 echo '},'; ?>
],


echo<<<print
                    fill: false,
                    pointHitRadius: 20,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Month'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Different point sizes'
                }
            }
        };

        $.each(config.data.datasets, function(i, dataset) {
            var background = randomColor(0.5);
            dataset.borderColor = background;
            dataset.backgroundColor = background;
            dataset.pointBorderColor = background;
            dataset.pointBackgroundColor = background;
            dataset.pointBorderWidth = 1;
        });

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
        };

        $('#randomizeData').click(function() {
            $.each(config.data.datasets, function(i, dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });

            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });

        $('#addData').click(function() {
            if (config.data.datasets.length > 0) {
                var month = MONTHS[config.data.labels.length % MONTHS.length];
                config.data.labels.push(month);

                $.each(config.data.datasets, function(i, dataset) {
                    dataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
                    if (Array.isArray(dataset.pointRadius)) {
                      dataset.pointRadius.push(Math.random() * 30);
                    }
                });

                window.myLine.update();
            }
        });

        $('#removeData').click(function() {
            config.data.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

            config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, datasetIndex) {
                dataset.data.pop();
                if (Array.isArray(dataset.pointRadius)) {
                  dataset.pointRadius.pop();
                }
            });

            window.myLine.update();
        });
    </script>
        print;
      die();
    } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So? What's the problem? Is it not working? Are you just looking for basic guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Hi maxim.. the php and js working but not toghter whem  trying to combine toghter... can you help me pls

Comment: @MaximHaytovich Can you?